# Conditionally display text in shiny UI, based on reactive data

Tags: r, shiny

I am writing a shiny app where I would like to display text in the UI, conditional upon the status of the dataframe that results from user inputs. All the solutions I have found point to g `conditionalPanel` and invoke solutions using inputs and java script notation. I don't want to base the condition on the user inputs, but on what the inputs do to the data.

Here is an reproducible example:

```
library('shiny')
library('tidyverse')

#Create the data
df <- data.frame('class' = c(rep('A', 20), rep('B', 5), rep('C', 6), rep('D', 11)), 
                 'value' = runif(42))
#Create the UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  #Select which class you want to include
  selectInput(inputId = 'class', 
              labe = 'Class', 
              choices = unique(df$class),
              selected = unique(df$class), 
              multiple = T), 
  
  #Plot based on the resulting classes
  plotOutput('plot'),
  
  #Output the data that i will be basing the condition on - just to make sure the analysis is working
  verbatimTextOutput('text')
  
  #proposed code for rendering the conditional 
  # if (TRUE %in% (df_selected_count()$n > 10) { #check if any of the counts are greater than 10
  #   HTML(
  #     paste(h3('Class with more than 10 values selected.'), '</br>')),
  # }
)

#Create the server    
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  #Filter by class to get the resulting plot
  df_selected <- reactive({
    df %>% filter(class %in% input$class)
  })
  
  #Create the plot on the reactive data
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = df_selected(),
           aes(x = class, y = value, col = class)) + 
      geom_jitter()
  })
  
  #Create the data frame on which i will base the conditional
  #Are classes selected with more than 10 values
  df_selected_count <- reactive({
    df_selected() %>%
      group_by(class) %>%
      summarize(n = n())
  }) 

  #Print the data 
  output$text <- renderPrint(df_selected_count())

}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The commented lines at the end of the UI are what I am imagining using to get the conditional HTML code to run. However that doesn't work.

Comment: Use `renderUI` and `uiOutput` but this will slow things down for very large datasets.

Comment: Why can’t you just print your text in another `textOutput`, similar to your existing `output$text`? If the condition isn’t satisfied, just “render” an empty string…

Comment: @NelsonGon Ok, i can look at that, but would prefer not to slow the app down - the data set will get quite large.

Comment: @Limey If i just use `output$text` i'll get a print bar on the app, which doesn't look great - especially when its an empty string. I tried creating a chr object based on   `text2 <- reactive({ ifelse(TRUE %in% (df_selected_count() > 10), 'Class with more than 10 values selected.', '')})`  However when i do that i can't call `text2()` in   `HTML(paste(h3(text2()), '<br/>')),`. Getting the error could not find function `text2()`

Comment: OK. The reason your solution doesn’t work is that the `ui()` function can’t access functions (ie reactives) defined in the `server()` function. The solution, as @NelsonGon suggests, is to use `uiOutput()` and `renderUI()`.

Comment: @Limey of course - i wasn't thinking clearly. First rendering the text output in the server and then calling it in the UI via `htmlOutput` worked. Posted the solution below. Thanks for the help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Limey's comment above I worked out that I needed to first render the text as an output before it would be available to the UI. I could then use `htmlOutput` to get a pretty print.

Solution is below.

```
library('shiny')
library('tidyverse')

#Create the data

df <- data.frame('class' = c(rep('A', 20), rep('B', 5), rep('C', 6), rep('D', 11)), 
                 'value' = runif(42))
#Create the UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  #Select which class you want to include
  selectInput(inputId = 'class', 
              label = 'Class', 
              choices = unique(df$class),
              selected = unique(df$class), 
              multiple = T), 
  
  #Plot based on the resulting classes
  plotOutput('plot'),
  
  #Output warning text if necessary (otherwise will be blank based on empty string)
  htmlOutput('text1'),
  
  #Output the data that i will be basing the condition on - just to make sure the analysis is working
  verbatimTextOutput('text2')
  
)

#Create the server    
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  #Filter by class to get the resulting plot
  df_selected <- reactive({
    df %>% filter(class %in% input$class)
  })
  
  #Create the plot on the reactive data
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = df_selected(),
           aes(x = class, y = value, col = class)) + 
      geom_jitter()
  })
  
  #Create the data frame on which i will base the conditional
  #Are classes selected with more than 10 values
  df_selected_count <- reactive({
    df_selected() %>%
      group_by(class) %>%
      summarize(n = n())
  })
  
  #Create the warning text - warning if TRUE, empty string if FALSE
  warning_text <- reactive({
    ifelse(TRUE %in% (df_selected_count()$n > 10),
           'Class with more than 10 values selected.',
           '') 
  })
  
  #Render the text so that it is available in the UI
  output$text1 <- renderText(warning_text()) 
  
  #Print the data 
  output$text2 <- renderPrint(df_selected_count())

}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: R's partial matching rules saved the day, but you misspelled `label` in your `selectInput`.